# WordPress query by category and children

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom query that will return results based upon the category status. If the category has children then I need to be able to query by both the parent and children. However if I am on a child category I need the query to be only the child. I've tried with get category parent but the functionality doesn't seem to be there. Can anyone help?

Current php code is:

```
if( $category[0]->category_parent != '' ) {
    $query_cat = $category[0]->slug;
} else {
    // Get parent category 
    $parent = &get_category($category[0]->term_id);
    if($parent->category_parent != 1) {
        $parent = $category[0]->term_id;
    }
    var_dump($parent);
} 
PERFORM NEW WP_Query();
```